# index formula,Vlookup formula in excel

Tags: excel

The query that i have is about the possibility of Vlookup or Index formula return the unique values

Consolidated information

```
letter  CoCode
a       1001
a       1124
b       1001
b       1002
b       1038
b       1158
c       1001
c       1038
```

query

```
a  ?
a  ?
b  ?
b  ?
```

Result expected after lookup

```
a   1001
a   1124
b   1001
b   1002
```

I have a consolidated info in column 1 & column 2 where the data has the letters and have the company code info in Column 2 and the result expected is list of company code as per the data available in consolidated base data and column where in a company code replicated once should not be repeated again.

Lets say if letter# a got the company code of 1001 in the lookup result.

next time that company code should not be replicated and it should show the next available company code for letter#a  which is 1124.

Can anyone help with a formula for this query?

Comment: What have you tried?!? Advanced filter does this handily.

Comment: Can you provide more information on how to use d advance filter

Comment: I used vlookup but it always results in providing the first information in column 2, let's say if I have a in my query twice,both the times it vl show 1001 itself, but I want 1124 for the second time for letter#a

Comment: what about the last 4 rows. It is also unique rite? Why is it not shown in the output

Comment: The reason is I want to know for any of the letters that I provide, the series may change, let's say I have ,b b a a in a column, I need in the beside column the company codes ex: the result is 1001,1002,1001,1124 this time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use INDEX with AGGREGATE to return the row:

```
=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)))/($A$2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A))=E1),COUNTIF($E$1:E1,E1)))
```

[image]

Comment: i guess there is some cell addressing issue, i only got the value in F2 cell, can you please look into it once?

Comment: and i gave the column 1 as letters for easy explanation, its actually a 7 digit invoice list as below  LETTER cocode
1000012 1001
1000012 1124
1000039 1001
1000039 1002
1000039 1038
1000039 1158
1000040 1001
1000040 1038

Comment: Did you copy/drag the formula down.  Put the formula in F2, then drag or copy that cell down.  Do not put the same formula in each cell.

Comment: The formula will auto change the E1 reference as it is copied or dragged down.

Comment: Yep. I dragged the formula, still I got the error as #num!

Comment: I guess the issue is the 7 digit customer number which I hv'nt mentioned in my question to explain my query easily, can u try the formula with 7 digit customer# list as I mentioned in my earlier comment?

Comment: That is because you are using numbers in Column A and not letters as your example showed, next time use the same type as the actual data.  It would help us not waste our time. See edit

Comment: apologies for the confusion raised scott, the edited formula gave me the result expected, you are awesome :)  Thanks a lot for the help and assistance provided !

Comment: @ShekarYelimela please mark as correct by clicking on the check mark by the answer.